# Android: creating circle button with background color programmatically

Tags: android, button, background, geometry

I am inflating dynamic buttons into TableRow with random colors. I would like to set the buttons to be in circle programmatically instead of rectangles.

### Code:

```
bt[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(color_normal[0], color_normal[1], color_normal[2]));
```

### Question:

Since the buttons are inflated dynamically with random colors, the button layout cannot be set through xml. How could a button be created with random colors and in circle shape programmtically? (Rather than placing a imageview with transparent center on top of the button)?

Thanks!

Comment: "the button layout cannot be set through xml.' what does it mean?

Comment: I dont know if I am wrong but I do not know how to pass a variable colorcode to the custom.xml such that the button can setBackground for the custom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Create a file oval.xml in the drawable folder that looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>

</shape>
```

Now set button as

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"

    android:layout_width="100dp"

    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:background="@drawable/oval_shape"

    android:text="Button" />
```

in your layout file.

Comment: can it be applicable for randomly generated colors instead of hard plug color code in xml?